# Rails How do I find case insensitive values that are not already associated to the user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Newbie Rails developer here so please bare with me.

I have a table called Ingredients where it contains a title field and an association to a User. A user can have many ingredients.

I want to query the database to get the ingredients that are not already available to a User.

I tried doing something like this with Rails:

```
@ingredients = current_user.ingredients
@community_ingredients = Ingredient.all.excluding(@ingredients).pluck(:title, :id)
```

But the problem is that this still returns values that are the same & only the case is different.

How can I achieve this outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following queries.

```rb
@community_ingredients = Ingredient.includes(:user).where("users.user_id = ?", current_user.id).where(users: { id: nil } ).pluck(:title, :id)

OR

Ingredient.includes(:user).where("users.user_id = ?", current_user.id).where(ingredients: {user_id: nil } ).pluck(:title, :id)

OR 

Ingredient.includes(:user).where("users.user_id = ?", current_user.id).where(users: { ingredient_id: nil } ).pluck(:title, :id)
```

Choose right query based on your association and feel free to suggest me so I can remove the extra one.

Most probably the first or second query will work, I strongly feel the third might not be the case.

---

Let's say this one is not working for you and you want to have solution based on your architecture.

```rb
@ingredients = current_user.ingredients.pluck(:title)
@community_ingredients = Ingredient.where.not("lower(title) IN (?)", @ingredients.map(&:downcase)).pluck(:title, :id)
```

So basically we need to convert both column value and the matching list in same case.
So we have converted to downcase.

here is how it looks in my local system, just make sure it's working that way.

[image]

Comment: Hey, I might be wrong here but the suggestions don't seem to be solving the case-sensitivity issue of the titles. For example, if I have an ingredient with an id:1 and title: Banana and someone else has an Ingredient with an id:2 and a title: banaNa then it should not return it.

Comment: Seems like the architecture needs to be corrected.
Why Ingredient is being stored in two different table, instead it should use foreign key of Ingredient table.

It could be many to many relation between Ingredient and user.
so you need a middle table.

But I'm updating my answer that into fit your current structure.

Comment: The ingredients aren't stored in two different tables, just one. In simple terms, I want to know what other users ingredients are excluding my own one's + ones that are similar irrespective of their case i.e. Banana banaNa.

Comment: To fix that you can convert the title to `Titlecase` while adding the record into database.
So this won't need any extra exercise while fetching.

Comment: @ShavinPeiris
What do you think?
Did I add anything useful?

Comment: I wish it was that easy to convert it to Titlecase but it affects the user's experience!

Comment: @engineersmnky can you please add one screenshot of what exactly you are seeing?

Comment: @engineersmnky just add round bracket around `?`
here is the updated query.

`@community_ingredients = Ingredient.where.not("lower(title) IN (?)", @ingredients.map(&:downcase)).pluck(:title, :id)`

I've tested this syntax in my local system and it's working.

Comment: @ShavinPeiris see the last query in my answer that will give you the result you want.

Comment: @HirenBhalani tried it out. I'm getting an undefined method error for downcase possibly because ingredients is a collection.

Comment: `.pluck(:title)` you misses this probably on the first query of fetching user's ingredients.

Comment: or you can try this.
`
@ingredients = current_user.ingredients
---------------------------------------------


@community_ingredients = Ingredient.where.not("lower(title) IN (?)", @ingredients.pluck(:title).map(&:downcase)).pluck(:title, :id)
`

Comment: It works! @HirenBhalani thank you! I'm wondering if it is an efficient implementation if there's a lot of records?

Comment: using pluck you are actually fetching only required columns, so it's time efficient but  not space efficient.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot the .pluck(:title) earlier, added it and it worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233194/discussion-between-shavin-peiris-and-hiren-bhalani).